# Elementor Pro form field validation using patterns - trouble adding custom error message

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I'm trying to add custom form field validation to our Elementor Pro forms to help ensure we have proper data hygiene.  I found some lovely [code which allows me to add a pattern field control](https://github.com/elementor/elementor/issues/8587) to the backend - which works well.  The only downside to this original code is that the error message for invalid input is that it only makes sense to developers (and maybe robots) because it echoes the validation pattern. I tried editing the code to add an additional field control for a custom error message that could be echoed, but I'm getting a syntax error from the function that should display the error message.  Any help figuring out what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated (also if the code can be streamlined, that's cool too).  I'm basically a monkey with a sledgehammer when it comes to coding.  What I've tried so far:

```
class Elementor_Forms_Patterns_Validation {

    public $allowed_fields = [
        'text',
        'email',
        'url',
        'password',
    ];

    public function __construct() {
        // Add pattern attribute to form field render
        add_filter( 'elementor_pro/forms/render/item', [ $this, 'maybe_add_pattern' ], 10, 3 );

        add_action( 'elementor/element/form/section_form_fields/before_section_end', [ $this, 'add_pattern_field_control' ], 100, 2 );

        add_action( 'elementor/element/form/section_form_fields/before_section_end', [ $this, 'add_validation_msg_field_control' ], 100, 2 );
    }

    /*
     * add_pattern_field_control
     * @param $element
     * @param $args
     */
    public function add_pattern_field_control( $element, $args ) {
        $elementor = \Elementor\Plugin::instance();
        $control_data = $elementor->controls_manager->get_control_from_stack( $element->get_name(), 'form_fields' );

        if ( is_wp_error( $control_data ) ) {
            return;
        }
        // create a new pattern control as a repeater field
        $tmp = new Elementor\Repeater();
        $tmp->add_control(
            'field_pattern',
            [
                'label' => 'Pattern',
                'inner_tab' => 'form_fields_advanced_tab',
                'tab' => 'content',
                'tabs_wrapper' => 'form_fields_tabs',
                'type' => 'text',
                'conditions' => [
                    'terms' => [
                        [
                            'name' => 'field_type',
                            'operator' => 'in',
                            'value' => $this->allowed_fields,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );

        $pattern_field = $tmp->get_controls();
        $pattern_field = $pattern_field['field_pattern'];

        // insert new pattern field in advanced tab before field ID control
        $new_order = [];
        foreach ( $control_data['fields'] as $field_key => $field ) {
            if ( 'custom_id' === $field['name'] ) {
                $new_order['field_pattern'] = $pattern_field;
            }
            $new_order[ $field_key ] = $field;
        }
        $control_data['fields'] = $new_order;

        $element->update_control( 'form_fields', $control_data );
    }
    
    /**
     * add_validation_msg_field_control
     * @param $element
     * @param $args
     */
    public function add_validation_msg_field_control( $element, $args ) {
        $elementor = \Elementor\Plugin::instance();
        $control_data = $elementor->controls_manager->get_control_from_stack( $element->get_name(), 'form_fields' );

        if ( is_wp_error( $control_data ) ) {
            return;
        }
        // create a new pattern control as a repeater field
        $tmp1 = new Elementor\Repeater();
        $tmp1->add_control(
            'field_validation_msg',
            [
                'label' => 'Validation Message',
                'inner_tab' => 'form_fields_advanced_tab',
                'tab' => 'content',
                'tabs_wrapper' => 'form_fields_tabs',
                'type' => 'text',
                'conditions' => [
                    'terms' => [
                        [
                            'name' => 'field_type',
                            'operator' => 'in',
                            'value' => $this->allowed_fields,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );

        $validation_msg_field = $tmp1->get_controls();
        $validation_msg_field = $validation_msg_field['field_validation_msg'];

        // insert new validation message field in advanced tab before field ID control
        $new_order = [];
        foreach ( $control_data['fields'] as $field_key => $field ) {
            if ( 'custom_id' === $field['name'] ) {
                $new_order['field_validation_msg'] = $validation_msg_field;
            }
            $new_order[ $field_key ] = $field;
        }
        $control_data['fields'] = $new_order;

        $element->update_control( 'form_fields', $control_data );
    }
    
    public function maybe_add_pattern( $field, $field_index, $form_widget ) {
        if ( ! empty( $field['field_pattern'] ) && ( ! empty( $field['field_validation_msg'] ) && in_array( $field['field_type'], $this->allowed_fields ) ) {

            $form_widget->add_render_attribute( 'input' . $field_index,
                [
                    // Add pattern attribute
                    'pattern' => $field['field_pattern'],
                    'validation_msg' => $field['field_validation_msg'],
                    // Add pattern to validation message
                    'oninvalid' => 'this.setCustomValidity( '$field['field_validation_msg']' )',
                    // Clear validation message when needed
                    'oninput' => 'this.setCustomValidity("")',
                ]
            );
        }
        return $field;
    }
}
new Elementor_Forms_Patterns_Validation();
```

Comment: Please include the full error message.